# how to Construct an HTTP request using Curl and Postman

Tags: ios, swift, curl, authorization, postman

[image][image]

I want to get response from this given data, my question is how to set the content type, accept, curl in postman in order to get the response. help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import curl commands directly by clicking on the *Import* button and then pasting the curl command in the *Paste Raw Text* tab:

[image]

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the guide.

Answer (score 1):

I am used to Postman,so i can help you on that.
1.First you have to select method type which is there beside URL field.
2.then go to header tab and there you can give key as Content-Type,Authorisation,Accept and in value field you can pass your values
ex-key ->"Content-Type" and value -> "application/json"

[image]